# Ruby's variable swap: x,y = y,x -- seems to be slower with array references?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I was just testing out some array operations and doing the ol'reverse-an-array problem (at high level) to see what the performance difference between Ruby's x,y = y,x swap and the typical use-a-temp-variable-to-swap method:

```
# using Ruby's swap
z = arr.length-1
for x in 0..(z/2)
  arr[x], arr[z - x] = arr[z - x], arr[x]
end

# using standard temp var
z = arr.length-1
for x in 0..(z/2)
  temp = arr[x]
  arr[x] = arr[z - x]
  arr[z - x] = temp
end
```

Ruby's shortcut swap is about 40 percent slower. I'm guessing there's some kind of extra array reference that's done? But I don't see where that extra operation would be done...I just assumed Ruby did a temp-var-swap behind the scenes.

edit: This is the benchmark I'm using:

```
def speed_test(n)
  t = Time.now
  n.times do
    yield
  end
  Time.now - t
end

tn = speed_test(TIMES) do
  # code...
end
```

And the array is just:

```
arr = 10000.times.map
```

Comment: Ruby is most likely creating a tuple object for (y,x), and then unpacking that tuple for the assignment to x,y.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that the problem is with your benchmark. Probably the first loop brings everything into the cache. Then the second loop runs identical code but it happens to be faster because the cache is fresh.

As a quick check of this, try reversing the order of the two loops!

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code to include the simple test function. I did as you suggested and no change in the results. If the array is just a list of primitives ([1,2,3,4...]), caching shouldn't take effect, right?